Combine avg() and if() functions "Avg(if())" in mySQL
I have the below table:



s.userid
c.userid
c.action




3
3
timeout


3
3
timeout


7
7
confirmed


7
7
confirmed


7
7
confirmed


2
2
timeout


2
2
confirmed



For a given s.user_id, I am trying to calculate
count(confirmed)/ (count(confirmed) + count(timeout))

So the end result should look like:
|s.userid | rate |
|---------|------|
|   3     |   0  |
|   7     |   1  |
|   2     |  0.5 |
I saw a solution where the following query was used:
select s.user_id, avg(if(c.action = 'confirmed', 1, 0)) as rate from *tablename* group by s.user_id;

I understand that the avg() function takes an expression and the if() function returns values based on a condition. I don't understand how this query works internally. If the if() function returns a value and the avg() function is expecting a numeric column, then what is the logical sequence of operations in this query?

Can any other actions appear beside those two?

@JonasMetzler I am trying to understand how if() and avg() functions work in conjunction with each other and group by. Although other solutions are welcome, it would be helpful to have an explanation on the if() avg() combo

That doesn't answer my question.

I am interested in understanding how the two functions work in conjunction. So I want an answer explaining how they operate together @JonasMetzler

I don't want any other actions with these two

Using conditional aggregation we can try:
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(action = 'confirmed') / SUM(action IN ('confirmed', 'timeout')) AS ratio
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;

If a given user might have neither confirmed nor timeout actions, then the above would give a divide by zero.  In that case, assuming you would want to report the ratio as zero, we can use case logic:
SELECT
    user_id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(action IN ('confirmed', 'timeout')) > 0
         THEN SUM(action = 'confirmed') / SUM(action IN ('confirmed', 'timeout'))
         ELSE 0
    END AS ratio
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;


This is a way to do it using LEFT JOIN :
SELECT t.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(t2.user_id) / SUM(t.user_id), 0) AS rate
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t.user_id = t2.user_id 
                     AND t.action = t2.action 
                     AND t2.action = 'confirmed'
GROUP BY t.user_id

